# Cordova Plugin include Android Library (Gradle)

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, cordova-plugins

I would like to include this Android [library](https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/fliclib-android) in a Cordova Plugin.

The library itself is managed by Gradle, as can be seen in the Github link. The developers of the library only provide [guide](https://flic.io/partners/developers/android-tutorial) how to use it in a Android Studio project, but I would like to create Cordova Plugin wrapper for this library, so I want to include it with the plugin.

My plugin has following structure:

```
-root
   -plugin.xml
   -lib
     -fliclib-android (this is a cloned library from the github link)
   -src
     -android
       -MyPlugin.java
   -www
     -MyPlugin.js
```

Inside of plugin.xml I have:

```
...
<js-module src="www/MyPlugin.js" name="MyPlugin">
    <clobbers target="MyPlugin" />
</js-module>

<!-- android -->
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="MyPlugin">
            <param name="android-package" value="com.mypackage.cordova.MyPlugin"/>
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/android/MyPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/mypackage/cordova" />
    <framework src="lib/fliclib-android/build.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />

</platform>
...
```

I have also tried:

```
<framework src="lib/fliclib-android/fliclib/build.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
<framework src="lib/fliclib-android/" custom="true" />
<framework src="lib/fliclib-android/fliclib/src/main/" custom="true" />
```

...
I have also tried creating my own Gradle file inside `lib/fliclib-android/fliclib/src/main`. So far no luck. When I try to run the `cordova build` process, what I usually end up with is bunch of errors indicating that no class/symbol from the library was loaded.

Is it even possible to include project like this? It would be also great if I could just reference it from Github, but in the docu I did not find such option. 
Or do I have to create an `aar` file? And load that? I have not tried that option, but I would like to try that only in the last resort case.

Thank you!

Comment: The thing is, the gradleReference is used to specify a gradle reference to build the project, they don't provide a gradle reference to add their library from gradle. So you can create a jar from their lib and add it to your project or add it as a project library, but not add it from gradle until they provide a reference

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thank you for your comment. I will probably go with the jar or aar file. One more thing: is it possible to create the gradle reference by myself? Maybe add some kind of .gradle file to the library folder?

Comment: I think you can publish it on maven central or jcenter so anybody can fetch it from there, but I think that's something the developers should do, not you. http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem was that even the android project containing the library was Gradle managed, they put the library there as a module, so that's why I couldn't reference it. I worked around this problem by creating aar file and referenced that into my project. If anybody experience similar problem with Flic library or some other, you can check out my solution on github: https://github.com/matej-pavla/FlicGap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed a different approach. It is funny that I developed the very same plugin and I didn't found your project!

My approach was to add a custom build.gradle file in my project. In the plugin.xml use the framework tag to specify the build.gradle location:

```
<!-- android -->
<platform name="android">
    <framework src="src/android/build.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
</platform>
```

Then, the build.gradle contents are as follows:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.50ButtonsEach:fliclib-android:ec1cdc3fbe'
}
```

It uses Jitpack to fetch the dependencies. It's working nice on Cordova, though I'm still having trouble building in the PhoneGap Build cloud solution.

This is my plugin, iOS support is on the way:

https://github.com/jguix/Cordova-Flic

Comment: Nice, one. I have never heard of `jitpack`. Glad that I did now :)

Comment: I have to thank you for your approach with the AAR file, I finally solved my problem in PhoneGap Build with that approach.