# Phone Gap android project build.gradle not working: could not find method complie()

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, phonegap

I am trying to compile the github project on Android Studio

https://github.com/jguix/Cordova-Flic

Taken from this stack overflow question

[Cordova Plugin include Android Library (Gradle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699752/cordova-plugin-include-android-library-gradle)

However I am getting the error:

`Error:(6, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.github.50ButtonsEach:fliclib-android:ec1cdc3fbe] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

from the build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.50ButtonsEach:fliclib-android:ec1cdc3fbe'
}
```

How should i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding that dependency in your project-level `build.gradle` file.

Add it in your app-level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: This is a plugin, I can't add it in the app-level. Also I changed the name from build.gradle to test.gradle and referenced that and now it is working. Any ideas why?