# Adding a custom Gradle dependency in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I have a Cordova app that targets Android API level 32 but relies on a legacy library that is no longer provided by Android SDK (org.apache.http.legacy).

Since the app relies on legacy plugins that use this library, I need to add it to the build somehow.

If I add it to the build.gradle file like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2"
    ...
}
```

the app works fine, however since the `build.gradle` file is generated by Cordova, it will be overwritten every time the app is re-generated.

Cordova documentation says I should add the dependency to the `config.xml` like this:

```
<platform name="android">
   ...
   <framework src="org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2" custom="true" type="gradleReference"/>
   ...
</platform>
```

However adding this snippet to the config does absolutely nothing.

How can I make Cordova add this dependency to the `build.gradle` file?

**Edit for clarification**: The plugin that depends on the legacy HTTP library is not mine, its a 3rd party plugin that's essential for the app.
The problem is, the plugin doesn't declare the legacy HTTP library as a dependency because it thinks it's already included in the Android SDK (which used to be true for old versions of the SDK, but not current ones).
Now I want to convince Cordova somehow to include the dependency somewhere in the generated build.gradle files, but everything I tried so far just doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cordova Plugin include Android Library (Gradle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34699752/cordova-plugin-include-android-library-gradle)

Comment: @Eric Not really. The other question refers to a plugin that the author wrote themselves. Still, I tried to implement the proposed solution as closely as possible for my case but it didn't work - the additional build.gradle and the <framework> tag seem to be simply ignored by Cordova.

Comment: I think your only move is to make a dummy plugin just for the sake of using the framework tag and embed your dependencies